# Use external database with Keycloak

Tags: database, keycloak

How to use an external SQL database with Keycloak?
I have a sql database that contains my clients from my application.

Answer (score 5):

If you have a pre-existing database with your own custom table structure for identity and access (most likely, you rolled your own `user` and `role` tables and probably some other tables as well), you can implement Keycloak's "User Storage SPI" in order to connect your database to Keycloak.

To do this, see [the docs](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/index.html#_user-storage-spi).